# NPM global install still creating a node_modules directory

Tags: npm, node-modules

In Ubuntu, I have a directory with my code `/code` which has my `packages.json` and such. My NPM prefix is `/usr` via `npm prefix -g`. I am trying to install packages globally so as to not create a `node_modules` directory in `/code`, but really as long as `node_modules` is not in `/code`, that will also work.

While in `/code`, I run `npm install -g`. I see a `.staging` directory created under my global prefix (eg, `/usr/lib/node_modules/.staging`) but then NPM takes another step and begins creating a `/code/node_modules` directory.

If I instead just run `npm install -g <package>` it correctly ends up in `/usr/lib/node_modules/<package>`. But I do not want to have to run `npm install -g <package>` for every package I need.

Why is NPM doing that and how can I make it stop doing that? At the very least, I would like the `node_modules` directory to NOT be in my `/code` directory (this is due to some environment constraints I can't change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globally installed packages are (almost always) not going to be used by your code. That's not how `node` or `npm` (conventionally) works. There isn't a shared global `node_modules` that programs all look in. (OK, there kinda is, but you don't want to use it if you can avoid it. Read on.) Having a local `node_modules` helps you avoid dependency hell. Global modules are for CLI tools that end up in your `PATH` and things like that.

You don't explain why you don't want a local `node_modules` for your project, so I will mention that if it is simply because it somehow bothers you, then please please please just get over it. You will be vastly happier. Type `npm install` and move on.

That said, for legacy reasons, your code in `/code` will look in `/node_modules` if there is no `/code/node_modules`. This is true for CommonJS modules that use `require()`. If you are using ESM modules via `import`, you may need to read the docs.

So, if you are using CommonJS/`require()`, you could have a directory structure like `/project-name/code`. You could have your `index.js` or whatever other code in the `code` subdirectory, while your `package.json` could be in `project-name`. Run `npm install` from `/project-name` and it will create a `node_modules` directory there rather than in the `code` subdirectory, and your Node.js files in `code` will find those modules.

If you don't like that, then for other options, you can review the [relevant docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#loading-from-the-global-folders). At the time of this writing, those options include a `NODE_PATH` environment variable, `$HOME/.node_modules`, `$HOME/.node_libraries`, and `$PREFIX/lib/node`. However it all comes with this caveat that I implore you to abide by if you can:

> It is strongly encouraged to place dependencies in the local node_modules folder. These will be loaded faster, and more reliably.

Comment: thanks, thats the info i was looking for. do you by chance know _why_ `node_modules` was still created despite the `-g` flag?

Comment: My guess would be that if you don't specify a module, the `-g` option doesn't make any sense. So it's probably ignored. But that's a guess. And I'm not sure it isn't a bug. Does seem like it ought to at least print a warning, if it wasn't doing that.